# How to make ActiveJDBC support more Postgres data types

Tags: postgresql, activejdbc

In the project I use postgresql as backend database. As the project grows, more data types, such as `uuid`, `jsonb`, `GEOGRAPHY` data types are involved. And I created the new `PostgreSQL2Dialect` class. Here is the template:

```
public class PostgreSQL2Dialect extends PostgreSQLDialect {

  @Override
  public Object overrideDriverTypeConversion(MetaModel mm, String attributeName, Object value) {
        // for select statement
        return ...;
  }
  
  @Override
  protected void appendValue(StringBuilder query, Object value, String ... replacements) {
       // for insert / update statement
    
  }
}
```

I found **I could not set the `PostgreSQL2Dialect` into `Dialects` class**. And I could not find any documents for supporting other data types in javalite website. Did I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

A dialect is automatically detected from a URL  and cannot be set from  outside. The [PostgreSQLDialect](https://github.com/javalite/javalite/blob/master/activejdbc/src/main/java/org/javalite/activejdbc/dialects/PostgreSQLDialect.java) class  already exists. If you want to make changes to it to extend with new functionality, please create a new issue: and propose a new feature there. A dialog with Q/A  will follow, and someone (maybe even you? ) will create a pull requersty with a new feature.